# How to know image has been downloaded in SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, sdwebimage

Currently I am integrating SDWebImage in my project,

1)`#import "UIButton+WebCache.h"`

2)`[button setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"]];`

Now I want to know when the image is downloaded successfully or not, How can I know this?

Comment: See [https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/585](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/585)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using the `setImageWithURL:` method and blocks like so:

Start your downloading animation. Then use this to download the image into an image view (or button, as you seem to be doing that above).

```
    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourPlaceholder.png"]
                        success:^(UIImage *image) {
                            // remove animation

                        }
                        failure:^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"thumbnail error: %@",error);
                            // handle failed download

                        }];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for latest version of SDWebImageManager

```
/**
* Check if image has already been cached
*/
- (BOOL)diskImageExistsForURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Comment: [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] diskImageExistsWithKey:(NSString*)url]

Answer (score 0):

Search for `memcache setObject` in the project, this line stores the image in cache once downloaded..
After this line, you can post a notification and check it in your own class.

Comment: So my main aim is to start animation of activity indicator once the image starts download and stop animation once download is complete,So does it help me to do so?